# How can I look up a value repeatedly in a loop from a switch block any faster

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a class that upon creation uses a large switch block to determine what one of its properties should be. For example:

```
swith unit
    case {'m'}
        y = 1;
    case {'in'}
        y = 0.0254;
    ...
    otherwise
        error('unit not found!')
end
```

This goes on for 30 or more cases, and it's decently quick on its own, but when this is done for several variables in a loop, it causes a noticable slowdown. Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to use indexing without creating all the values I want to index into first which I think would also be too slow. Is there any way to do this faster/more efficiently?

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare code, really hard to read and follow.  A dictionary may create better code, more readable and faster. Dictionaries in MATLAB are called `containers`:https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Comment: I wrote an answer which used `containers.Map` but it was around 5 times slower on a case with 26 options than just using a switch (even removing the time to create the map, which was even slower), and profiling the switch code it runs extremely quickly. Please can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows this being your bottleneck?

Comment: `when this is done for several variables in a loop` I strongly suspect something is wrong with your loop, mostly because I don't think it's possible to use a loop to assign variables without using something like an `eval` statement. You either have the variables and they all have unique names, or you have a vector of parameters and you can easily botch a transpose and wind up with a (sometimes very large) square matrix instead of a vector. You also might have missed an indexing operation and you're looping through all the parameters all the time, etc. Show us the loop and how you're indexing.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, That sounds like just the thing I need. I'll see if it'll help.

Comment: @Chuck This is part of a class that adds units to values, and pretty much every time you perform an operation between two different values with units the units need to be recreated somewhat, and looking up on that table is the bottleneck, even with a lot of optimization. A single operation may take less than a millisecond, but compounded over the course of a program it adds up.

Comment: Why are you looking it up? Just store a `conversion_factor` when the class is created. If you mean you've got a class that accepts a number and string/char array then that's not really so much a class as a function, right? You can make a class that's just a `value` and `conversion_factor` and it's created by passing a `unit`. On construction you do the switch statement - *one time* - and use it to choose your conversion factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to @Wolfie's now-deleted answer in which they use a `containers.Map`. The problem with `containers.Map` is that it is a custom class (it comes with MATLAB, but it's not built into the interpreter, it's M-file code). Instead, we two arrays as follows:

```matlab
key = {'m', 'in'};
value = [1, 0.0254];
[~, index] = ismember(unit, key);
if index == 0
   error('unknown units')
end
y = value(index);
```

This is not as pretty as using a `containers.Map`, but is significantly faster.

I don't know if this is faster than a `case` statement though. I don't think the `case` itself is your bottleneck, but rather that you call it unnecessarily often. Consider whether you need to do this lookup *every single time* you create an object of this class, or whether you can delay or avoid the loopup altogether.